# SwiftUI: How to change the speed of drag based on distance already dragged?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

For example: I have a joystick that can be moved around freely, how can I make the dragging slower with distance? The further I drag the joystick, the slower the drag is.
Thanks in advance.

My Joystick code, dragging works but has no bounds and isn’t slowed down if you drag it to the edges:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var isDragging = false
    @State var dragValue = CGSize.zero

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("width: \(dragValue.width)")
            Text("height: \(dragValue.height)")
            VStack (spacing: 16) {
                HStack(spacing: 35) {
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)


                    VStack (spacing: 80) {
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.up")
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)

                    }
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)

                }


            }
            .offset(x: dragValue.width * 0.05, y: dragValue.height * 0.05)

            .frame(width: 150, height: 150)

            .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)), Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.8705882353, green: 0.8941176471, blue: 0.9450980392, alpha: 1))]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: isDragging ? (55 - abs(dragValue.height) / 10) : 55, style: .continuous))
            .offset(x: dragValue.width, y: dragValue.height)

            .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.2), radius: 20, x: 0, y: 20)
            .padding(.horizontal, 30)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture().onChanged { value in
                    self.dragValue = value.translation
                    self.isDragging = true
                }
                .onEnded { value in
                    self.dragValue = .zero
                    self.isDragging = false
                }
            )
                .animation(.spring(response: 0.5, dampingFraction: 0.6, blendDuration: 0))
        }

    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is possible solution based on asymptotic curve (if somebody find it helpful).

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

#### Update: retested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo]

Changed part

```
DragGesture().onChanged { value in
    let limit: CGFloat = 200        // the less the faster resistance 
    let xOff = value.translation.width
    let yOff = value.translation.height
    let dist = sqrt(xOff*xOff + yOff*yOff);
    let factor = 1 / (dist / limit + 1)
    self.dragValue = CGSize(width: value.translation.width * factor,
                        height: value.translation.height * factor)
    self.isDragging = true
}
```